# onclick of a widget in pygtk, display other widgets

Tags: python-2.7, widget, gtk, pygtk, olpc

I want to create a ToolButton widget in pygtk that displays ToolItem widget on its click.. I have a file that contains all classes of widgets(say widgets.py) and another file(say demo.py) that instantiates these widgets and are then inserted into a toolbar.

Demo.py

```
class Demo(activity.Activity):
    def __init__(self,activity):
        toolbar_box = ToolbarBox()
        self.set_toolbar_box(toolbar_box)
        toolbar_box.toolbar.insert(MathButton(self), -1)
        toolbar_box.toolbar.insert(MathStartTitleEntry(self), -1)
        toolbar_box.show_all()
```

Widgets.py

```
class MathButton(ToolButton):
    def __init__(self,activity, **kwargs):
        ToolButton.__init__(self,'add',**kwargs)
        self.props.tooltip = _('Start Maths Game')
        self.connect('clicked', self.mathfun, activity)
    def mathfun(self, button, activity):
        activity.close()

class MathStartTitleEntry(gtk.ToolItem):
    def __init__(self,activity, **kwargs):
        gtk.ToolItem.__init__(self)
        self.entry = gtk.Entry(**kwargs)
        self.entry.set_size_request(int(gtk.gdk.screen_width() / 9),-1)
        self.entry.set_text("Start ")
        self.entry.set_property("editable", False)
        self.entry.unset_flags(gtk.CAN_FOCUS)
        self.entry.show()
        self.add(self.entry)
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I am displaying both the widgets together in the toolbar at same time..and have written a function in button widget class i.e wen it is clicked it returns true and den, in file.py I instantiated the button widget in an if loop and in which I further instantiated the other widget..but dats not working

Comment: You should post the code that you think is problematic. Like that, the chance is greater that people will help you. Read the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour  and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179268/show-examples-of-good-and-bad-questions

Comment: I want on click of the MathButton widget in toolbar, the other widget MathStartTitleEntry to be displayed, till den only the MathButton should be visible on the toolbar.